# Java библиотека для быстрых IO операций с текстом (URL > String, File > String)

Tags: java

Я что-то делаю не так или почему я не могу найти библиотеку позвояющую в простой форме получать данные из файла или контент по ссылке?

Доволно часто приходится получать, например, контент ссылки, я могу использовать Apache IOUtils:

```
IOUtils.toString(new URL("http://..."), "UTF-8")
```

Но почему не сделать просто

```
SomeLibWithFastFunctions.getUrlContent("http://...");
```

Т.е. минимум кода, там где это допустимо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Потому что [декомпозиция](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%B1%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85), [принцип единственной ответственности](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BF_%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8) и [слабое зацепление](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_(%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)). В частности, метод получающий данные по ссылке не должен проверять валидность ссылки. К тому же ничто не мешает вам сделать свою обёртку:

```
public class MyLibWithFastFunctions {
    public static String getUrlContent(String url) {
        return IOUtils.toString(new URL(url), "UTF-8");
    }
}
```

Comment: Получается, что такой подход противоречит правильной концепции программирования на Java (и не только), но как инструмен для набросков разве такой универсальный набор не будет полезен? Возможно я еще не привык, но когда нужно что-то быстро проверить - приходится брать PHP или копировать набор функций из одного тестового проекта в другой.

Comment: Противоречит ООП в любом языке. Java - не очень подходящий язык для набросков. Взгляните в сторону Groovy - та же платформа, тот же синтаксис, чуть больше возможностей, но существенно меньше ограничений и нет необходимости в этапе компиляции.

Comment: Как альтернатива PHP - да. Лучше конечно, возможно даже выход. Но все равно еще один язык. Или подбить свою библиотеку и смириться.